# Find smallest integer $n$ so that $\sqrt{\frac{1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2}n}$ is an integer

Tags: square-numbers

> Find smallest positive integer $n$ (not equal to $1$) so that $\frac{1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2}n$ is a perfect square.

I tried to use : $1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$

That gives us $\frac{1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2}n=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}6$

I tried to brute-force it using python, and I got $n=337$, but I should probably use modular arithmetic (or something else).

Comment: Does $1$ count as a perfect square ?

Comment: Looks like a Pell's equation problem.

Comment: @Peter $1=1^2=1 \cdot 1$, so why wouldn't it be?

Comment: According to PARI/GP, $337$ is the smallest solution beyond $1$

Comment: @Landuros Usually, perfect powers do not include trivial powers like $1^n$ or $n^1$

Comment: So the answer *is* indeed 337, as you already found out ...?

Comment: If you're asking for an easier way to come up with 337, I think only modular arithmetic would help to figure out which things you could skip in your tests.

Comment: $n\equiv 1, 6\mod{6}$

Answer (score 9):

You want to solve
$$(n+1)(2n+1)=6m^2.$$
This is
$$16n^2+24n+8=48m^2$$
or
$$(4n+3)^2-48m^2=1.$$
This is basically Pell's equation $x^2-48y^2=1$, but with the extra
stipulation $x\equiv3\pmod 4$. The positive solutions of this
 Pell equation are given by
$$x_k+y_k\sqrt{48}=(7+\sqrt{48})^k.$$
The solutions with $x_k\equiv 3\pmod 4$ are those with $k$ odd. The
first is $x_1=7$ giving $n=1$. The next is $x_3=1351$ giving $n=337$.
The next is $x_5=262087$ giving $n=65521$, etc.

Comment: Can you explain Pell's equation a little more?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

Comment: @BilalHIMITE See Pell's equation I and II [on Keith Conrad's page](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/).

Comment: Desperately trying to see anyhow to unstuck this problem except from using pell the diophantine savior. no luck.